# Debugging PHP codes

Tags: php

I am following [this tutorial](http://robsnotebook.com/php_debugger_pdt_xdebug)

**STEPS**

```
Downloaded Xdebug - PHP VC 11 64 bit [Didn't download TS version - ]
```

My php is 5.6.11 vc 11

```
Added zend extensions with right dll path
```

Started server. Zend extension is added. Checked with `phpinfo()`

```
Downloaded Eclipse PDT

Opened Eclipse and created new project and given path to my files

Localhost server so didn't change PHP->Servers

Debug configurations
   Changed server to XDebug
   Added a file to debug
```

Started the server. It opens in mozilla [`I changed default web browser to mozilla in eclipse`]

But it didn't stop at my breakpoints

```
<?php

$x = 2;
$y = 5;
$z = $x + $y;
echo $z;

?>
```

Did I miss any step? Or is there any other way to achieve debugging PHP? 
Any Suggestions?

Comment: Are you using WAMPServer or XAMPP or did you install Apache/PHP individually

Comment: @RiggsFolly No. Its manual setup of Apache, PHP, MYSQL.

Comment: Is PHP running as an Apache module or FastCGI

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Server API is Apache 2.0 module

Comment: PS. There is no PHP5.6.21 do you mean PHP5.5.21

Comment: If PHP is run as an apache module you will need the Thread Safe version of anything you add to PHP so try the `TS` version of XDEBUG

Comment: Also this [XDEBUG Tailored installation Instructions](http://xdebug.org/wizard.php) should do most of the heavy lifting for you

Comment: @RiggsFolly - My php is 5.6.11 thread safe version. I will try and tell you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83714/discussion-between-gops-ab-and-riggsfolly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct version of the XDEBUG dll to match your Apache/PHP installation.

If you have PHP installed as an Apache module you need the Thread Safe XDEBUG dll. If you have PHP installed as CGI/FastCGI then you want the Non Thread Safe XDEBUG dll.

Its a good idea to use the [XDEBUG Wizard](http://xdebug.org/wizard.php)

That will tell you exactly what to modify in your `php.ini` and which dll you should download.

Beware of old tutorials, they may suggest using the old and now defunct `zend_extension_ts=` when you should use `zend_extension=`

Also on windows systems use the unix forward slash and not the dos backslash in the path to the XDEBUG dll like so :-

```
zend_extension="C:/server/php/ext/php_xdebug-2.3.3-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll"
```